# Add new database to SSMS

Tags: ssms-2016

Trying to add Progress Open Edge database into ACCESS 2016 that is already connected to SQL Server Express. Spoke with the folks at Progress and they sent me a paper on how to do it via SSMS. I have the Progress ODBC driver installed and the test connection works. I followed the instructions from Progress and I can see an entry for the Open Edge DB in the tables tab in SSMS, but when I try to open the tables tab I get the following error:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. Named pipes Providor: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].(Microsoft SQL Server error: 53)

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of Progress Open Edge database.  But I note you state "into Access 2016" but the remainder of your post appears to be primarily concerned on connecting POE to the SQL Server tables.

So I'm wondering if there is some confusion in your terminology.  My interpretation is that Access 2016 is a front end to the SQL Server, which is common, and that you are attempting to do a similar set up with POE linking it to SQL Server.  But that there is no linking between POE and Access (which there should not be....).

Comment: Here are the instructions I used:

Comment: According the instructions I can set up POE as a database in SSMS using POE ODBC.  The POE ODBC Connects successfully.  But when I try to open the tables tab I get the 53 Error.  IN ACCESS I can see the link to the POE but can't open the tables.  2 parts I guess.  First, I just want to see the POE tables in SSMS.  Then I'll attempt to open them in ACCESS.

Comment: Am confused. SSMS = SQL Server Management System.  It doesn't itself hold tables, it manages the tables in SQL Server.  ...  nothing here involves Access at all......

Comment: Distilled- Can I read a progress Open Edge database and ignore the indexes.  That is the is the long and short of it. If yes, how.